# How do you convert a base64 value to a hex value using Qt /KDE?

Tags: qt, cryptography, kde-plasma

I am working a software that uses Qt and  has existing methods to encrypt/decrypt checksum values in hex. Currently, I've encountered some checksum values that are in base 64. Instead of reinventing the wheel  to do the same stuff for base64 checksum, I was wondering if there is a way to convert a base64 value to a hex value using Qt or KDE libs . This way I'd save myself from writing semi duplicate code to do the almost similar task.

Here is how it should work:

```
Input: VO2S9pgCq1lqgTFTKssVj6amn0npNdagtjI8ziDtiRQ=
Output: 54ed92f69802ab596a8131532acb158fa6a69f49e935d6a0b6323cce20ed8914
```

The input is contained in a QString. 
Also in case there is no built in support in Qt/KDE can you suggest me a method in C++ ?

Comment: Sorry let me edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I tried right now:

```
 QString b64("VO2S9pgCq1lqgTFTKssVj6amn0npNdagtjI8ziDtiRQ=");
 QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromBase64(b64.toAscii());

 QString res(ba.toHex());

 qDebug() << res;
```

Probably there's a more correct way to do it, but I'm too sleepy right now, sorry.

As a function:

```
 /// untested
 QString base64ToHex(const QString& b64){
     QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromBase64(b64.toAscii());
     QString res(ba.toHex());

     return res;      
 }
```

or simply..

```
 QString base64ToHex(const QString& b64){
     return QString(QByteArray::fromBase64(b64.toAscii()).toHex());
 }
```

Edit 1: with Qt5 you should use `QString::toLatin1()` instead of `QString::toAscii()`.